# Start Writting middle Centre of the slide and increased font size in a particular line in LaTex Beamer

Tags: beamer, themes

I am making a presentation in LaTex Beamer, So in last slide I would like to start writing from middle center of the last slide. how to start from the middle center of the slide.

Below command now I am using which put my line on top of centre in the slide, but I want the line should start middle of the centre. additionally, i want to increase the font size of the particular line. how it would be done.

Thanks in advance

```
\section{}
 \begin{frame}
 \centering
 \textbf {Thank You for the attention}\\Suggestions for providing additional services /informations are most welcome 

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not just post code fragments, but always a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). The default beamer behaviour is to place text vertically centred - so you are doing something non-standard if your text is at the top of the frame.

I assume you might be using `\documentclass[t]{beamer}`? Then you can tell an individual slide to centre the content by using `\begin{frame}[c]`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]
    \centering
    \textbf{\Large Thank You for the attention}

    Suggestions for providing additional services/informations are most welcome
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfectly working. one more thanks I would like to know the function of C, and how to spread line spacing between two sentences.

Comment: @SWAT `c` stand for centre and localy undoes your instruction for top alignment.

Comment: @SWAT As for increasing the space between the sentences, there are many possibilities, for example `\bigskip Suggestions ...` or `\vspace*{1cm}` ...

Comment: @SWAT Maybe you are interested in http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/ It's a free ebook and you can find things like linespacing or fontsizes there